How do I find the branch of the last commit merged into master using the API?
I have a branch, e.g. my-branch, containing multiple commits.
I squash and merge the branch's PR into master using the Github UI
I then use the Github API to get the last commit that was just merged into master by doing:
const [lastMergedCommit] = await fetch(`${githubApiBaseUrl}/repos/${owner}/${repo}/commits?sha=master&per_page=1`)

Now I've found solutions that try to extract the name of the branch from lastMergedCommit.commit.message by using a Regex and assuming that lastMergedCommit.commit.message will consist of:
Merge pull request #{PR ID} from ${branch name}

but this doesn't seem bullerproof at all since I've noticed that "merge" commits don't always contain the branch name or have the above structure at all.
So I'd like to know if there is a bulletproof way of discerning the name of the branch that lastMergedCommit belonged to before it was merged into master, by using the contents of lastMergedCommit.

probably not bulletproof but how about getting the pr list https://api.github.com/repos/lichess-org/lila/pulls?state=closed&base=master&sort=updated&direction=desc

hmm i actually think this might be it. just ignorign the "merged_at": null entries and can get the branch from head.label. what do you think
